# Unable to visualize segmented pointcloud in rviz

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, pcl, message-filter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I used the segmentation code in the http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/planar_segmentation.php to segment the pointclouds published by the kinect.

I just have the inliers into the resulting cloud and assign NAN to the rest of the points in cloud. I saved the resulting file in a pcd file and tried to view that using pcd_viewer which works fine.

But when i try to visualize the same on the rviz i get the following error

```
[ WARN] [1324985289.408678181]: MessageFilter [target=/openni_depth_frame ]: Discarding message from [/segment_pcl] due to empty frame_id.  This message will only print once.
```

I searched for the solution and came to know that the header should be set for the node. I didn't get information on how to do that. Can some one help me with this. It would be lot better to visualize things on rviz than storing the pcd files and use pcd_viewer.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12469/unable-to-visualize-segmented-pointcloud-in-rviz/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2011-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A frame ID is a string defined via the [`tf` package](http://ros.org/wiki/tf). To display your point cloud in context with other messages, `rviz` needs a `frame_id` in the message `Header` to transform those data into the fixed frame.

You could just make up a frame ID to publish and select it as the `rviz` fixed frame, but following the [REP-0105 naming conventions](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html#coordinate-frames) probably will work better.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2